# WPF binding selected item in datagrid to a second datagrid and show value depending of it

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I have two WPF datagrids. When a row is selected from first datagrid, dg1, a column called 'Notes' in second datagrid, dg2, should be shown as empty strings only and only if the content of the column 'Note Type' for the selected row in dg1 is equal to "I". Otherwise, content of 'Notes' column in dg2 should be the one from collection ItemsDg2 that comes from Notes.

My problem is that when value is "I", the content of 'Note Type' column in dg1 is shown in column 'Notes' of dg2 instead of showing an empty string.

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow"
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">


   <my:DataGrid Name="dg1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsDg1}">
       <my:DataGrid.Columns>
          <my:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="iType" Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Header="Note Type"/>
       </my:DataGrid.Columns>   
   </my:DataGrid>

   <my:DataGrid Name="dg2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsDg2}">      
       <my:DataGrid.Columns>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Notes}" Header="Notes">
                <my:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">                                       
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Notes}"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Type, ElementName=dg1}" Value="I">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </my:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </my:DataGridTextColumn>
        </my:DataGrid.Columns>          
   </my:DataGrid>

</Window>
```

ItemsDg1 is a List of It1

ItemsDg2 is a List of It2

```
public Class It1
{

    private string _type;
    public string Type
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set
        {
            if (!_type.Equals(value))
            {
                _type = value;
            }
        }
    }

}

public Class It2
{

    private string _notes;
    public string Notes
    {
        get { return _notes; }
        set
        {
            if (!_notes.Equals(value))
            {
                _notes = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Classes It1 and It2 have more properties but I only show here the minimum to understand the scenario. The same applies to dg1 and dg2, they have more datagrid columns.

Comment: This is very confusing.  Are you saying `ItemsDg1` and `ItemsDg2` contain the same number of items, with each item in `ItemsDg2` corresponding to the item at the same index in `ItemsDg1`?  If so, why are you structuring it that way?

Comment: @MikeStrobel No, ItemsDg1 and ItemsDg2 don't have the same number of items.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly after I fixed the stuff that wouldn't compile (`Class`, there's no `DataGrid` in that namespace) and the stuff that wouldn't run (in your version, you can't set `_type` to non null until after you call `_type.Equals()`). Whatever problem you have in your real code, you fixed it when you created this example. Or are you actually using a different DataGrid control? If so, where can I find it to test with?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should get the results you want by replacing the `Notes` column definition in `dg2` as follows:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Notes">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock x:Name="CellText" Text="{Binding Notes}" />
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Type, ElementName=dg1}" Value="I">
          <Setter TargetName="CellText" Property="Text" Value="" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I have done it but it does not work. I have added a converter to pass SelectedItem.Type to it. This converter returns True or False. Then instead of comparing value against "I" in DataTrigger I compare it against "True". I have seen that the SelectedItem.Type is not being fired as I have put a breakpoint within the converter and It never stops. Example: <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Type, ElementName=dg1, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" Value="I">

Comment: @user1624552 Are you changing the `Type` property at runtime?  If so, you'll need to make your item classes implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when a property changes, or else the binding won't know that it needs to be reevaluated.